# Using same code for multiple subdomain and different database

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I am trying to create a system where each user gets their own subdomain like *a.mysite.com*, *b.mysite.com* etc. Both **a** and **b** subdomain will have their own database (different DB name, user and password). But I don't want to copy and paste my system code on both **"a"** and **"b"** subfolder. Its redundant and if I have 100 subdomain eventually, a minor edit to the code has to be done at 100 places which is as you can fell is a bad practice.

So, I am running out of ideas here and am not finding a proper way to tackle this problem. Any solution to this problem will really help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Have one instance of your system in a folder above the html root and in every new subdomain create a file (automatically) that has the configuration of the user (database, settings, etc) and a function that summon the system.

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to do. better describe the problem and give some examples. 

beside these, if there is no a "high order necessity" which bounds the internal structure of your application, different databases for every user is meaningless. single database with associated tables (many to many, one to many etc.) would be enough.